# Help needed with PDF and independent value

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

A continuous random variable, X, has probability density function given by
() =  − 2
for 0≤≤2
= 0 elsewhere
Observation on X indicate that the mean is 1

part a) show a = 1.5 and find b

i've done this part and i got b as 0.75

part b) If two independent observations are made on X what is the probability that at
least one of them is less than 0.5

Idk how about to go this part? Should I take observation 1 - observation 2 < 0.5 and solve like continuous random variable? any sort of hint would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Given that the continuous random variable $X$ has probability density function
$$f(x) = ax - bx^2, \quad 0 \leq x \leq 2$$
and 0 elsewhere, we have
$$1 = \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x) dx = \int_0^2 f(x) dx = \int_0^2 (ax - bx^2) dx = \left[\frac{a}{2}x^2 - \frac{b}{3}x^3\right]\bigg|_0^2 = 2a - \frac{8}{3}b.$$
Given also that $E[X] = 1$, we have
$$1 = E[X] = \int_{-\infty}^\infty xf(x) dx = \int_0^2 xf(x) dx = \int_0^2 (ax^2 - bx^3) dx = \left[\frac{a}{3}x^3 - \frac{b}{4}x^4\right]\bigg|_0^2 = \frac{8}{3}a - 4b.$$
Solving these two equations together, we obtain
$$a = \frac{3}{2} = 1.5, \quad b = \frac{3}{4} = 0.75.$$

For part b), we observe $X_1, X_2 \overset{i.i.d.}{\sim} f(x)$. The probability that at least one of them is less than 0.5 is given by
\begin{align*}
P(X_1 < 0.5 \text{ or } X_2 < 0.5) &= 1 - P(X_1 \geq 0.5 \text{ and } X_2 \geq 0.5)\\
&= 1 - P(X_1 \geq 0.5)P(X_2 \geq 0.5) \quad (\text{by independence})\\
&= 1 - [P(X_1 \geq 0.5)]^2 \quad (\text{by identically distributed})\\
&= 1 - \left[\int_{0.5}^2 f(x)dx\right]^2\\
&= 1 - \left[\int_{0.5}^2 (1.5x - 0.75x^2)dx\right]^2\\
&= 1 - \left[\left[\frac{3}{4}x^2 - \frac{1}{4}x^3\right]\bigg|_{0.5}^2\right]^2\\
&= 1 - \left[\left(3 - 2\right) - \left(\frac{3}{16} - \frac{1}{32}\right)\right]^2\\
&= 1 - \left(\frac{27}{32}\right)^2\\
&= \frac{295}{1024}\\
(&= 0.2880859375)
\end{align*}